# Get URI VAR from SynapseXPath Variable in WSO2 ESB API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to get a URI VAR value from request to call correct case in switch in WSO2 ESB API resource, like this:

```
<api name="apk" context="/apk"><resource methods="GET" uri-
template="/apk/{appName}"><inSequence><header name="App" 
scope="transport" action="remove"/><switch source="get-
property('uri.var.appName')"><case regex="BEBE"><send><endpoint><http 
method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost/apk/Bebe.apk></http>
</endpoint></send></case><case regex="CITAS"><send><endpoint><http 
method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost/apk/Citas.apk></http>
</endpoint></send></case></switch></inSequence></resource></api>
```

In switch, `source="get-property('uri.var.appName')"` it's not correct.

Can I get this value using `$url` SynapseXpath valiables like `$url`?

Answer (score 6):

What you have done is correct. Please try the same with a log mediator and see whether you get the value properly.

```
<log level="custom">
    <property name="AppName" expression="get-property('uri.var.appName')"/>
</log>
```

Alternatively you can assign this to a property and use that inside your switch mediator.